# Unix : Compare two TXT file issue and keep the lines which is not unique

Tags: bash, csv, unix, comm

I have two `TXT` files as

```
#1.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5

#2.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
6.6.6.6
7.7.7.7
8.8.8.8
```

I made comparison of `1.txt` to `2.txt` and get the IPs which is not in `2.txt`   when comparing with `1.txt` . I did,

```
#comm -2 -3 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) > Out.txt
```

Output

```
#Out.txt
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

The `Out.txt` IPs are the IPs not in `2.txt` file.

Now,I would like compare `1.txt` against `2.txt` and get the one which is not unique from `1.txt` .

```
#1.txt
1,1.1.1.1
2,2.2.2.2
3,3.3.3.3
4,4.4.4.4
5,5.5.5.5

#2.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
6.6.6.6
7.7.7.7
8.8.8.8
```

Expected Result

```
#Out.txt
3,3.3.3.3
4,4.4.4.4
5,5.5.5.5
```

How to include IDs in my output result ?

Comment: `I would like compare 1.txt against 2.txt and get the one which is not unique from 1.txt ` don't understand, why `11111` not in output? four 1s and five ones are different aren't they?

Comment: oh, I see, it is **comma**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this awk one-liner should work for your example:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($2 in a)' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @kent ! Worked perfect !